# Unable to run distributed tests with JMeter 5.4.1 using SSL RMI and defined ports on linux

Tags: ssl, jmeter, load-testing, firewall, distributed-testing

I am running Jmeter 5.4.1 using openjdk 11 across all Linux machines. I tried using ubuntu 18.04.5, ubuntu 20.04.2, and Debian 10 which all had the same issues. I am able to run tests with specified ports or RMI SSL enabled but not both together. Everything works until I set client.rmi.localport then it has errors. Currently I don't have the firewall enabled as I was trying to eliminate obstacles. Nothing is on the specified ports until Jmeter runs (1099, 4888, 5888, 5889, 5900 are free and open). These are the changes I made to the `user.properties` file.

Client (Master)

```
remote_hosts=172.xx.xxx.xx1,172.xx.xx.xx2
server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=/home/user/rmi_keystore.jks
client.rmi.localport=5888
```

Server (Slave)

```
server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=/home/user/rmi_keystore.jks
server.rmi.localport=4888
```

/etc/hosts file looks like this on each machine just with the last number of ip changed and hostname to reflect that.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       xxx-l1.xxx.xxxx.xxx  xxx-l1
172.xx.xxx.xx1  xxx-l1.xxx.xxxx.xxx  xxx-l1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Currently trying to get it to work in GUI or command line but mostly been using the GUI to test with. I tried using either below to start the Client and run the tests.

```
./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.xx.xxx.xx8

JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m" ./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.xx.xxx.xx8
```

If its a simple test only hitting google.com in the gui I'm able to run the distributed test once to success and then after that when rerunning the test it has these errors in the Client log and nothing generated in the Server log. If its a more complicated test or just including something as a view results tree on the first run it will show the errors. Command line also fails first run. The other log I have seen says Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) inplace of the java.io.NotSerializableException but still shows same port messages.

```
2021-07-09 09:57:17,008 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/home/user/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin'
2021-07-09 09:57:17,011 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: /home/user/Desktop/Summer2021/basictest.jmx
2021-07-09 09:57:17,012 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/home/user/Desktop/Summer2021'
2021-07-09 09:57:17,208 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2021-07-09 09:57:17,226 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2021-07-09 09:57:17,228 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2021-07-09 09:57:17,230 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /home/user/Desktop/Summer2021/basictest.jmx
2021-07-09 09:57:17,255 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-07-09 09:57:17,255 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-07-09 09:57:17,255 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-07-09 09:57:17,255 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-07-09 09:57:17,255 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2021-07-09 09:57:17,255 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2021-07-09 09:57:17,383 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/home/user/Desktop/Summer2021'
2021-07-09 09:57:23,234 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 172.xx.xxx.xx1
2021-07-09 09:57:24,033 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting distributed test with remote engines: [172.xx.xxx.xx1] @ Fri Jul 09 09:57:24 MDT 2021 (1625846244032)
2021-07-09 09:57:24,033 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2021-07-09 09:57:24,034 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2021-07-09 09:57:24,034 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2021-07-09 09:57:24,254 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': 172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:24,254 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:24,256 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-07-09 09:57:24,452 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/172.xx.xxx.xx8,localport=5890]]
2021-07-09 09:57:24,455 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': 172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:24,455 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:24,655 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/172.xx.xxx.xx8,localport=5889]]
2021-07-09 09:57:25,209 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 172.xx.xxx.xx1 basedir='.'
2021-07-09 09:57:25,209 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {}
2021-07-09 09:57:25,212 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 172.xx.xxx.xx1
2021-07-09 09:57:25,213 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started:[172.xx.xxx.xx1]
2021-07-09 09:57:25,214 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, 172.xx.xxx.xx1)
2021-07-09 09:57:25,445 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, 172.xx.xxx.xx1)
2021-07-09 09:57:29,906 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 172.xx.xxx.xx1
2021-07-09 09:57:30,347 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting distributed test with remote engines: [172.xx.xxx.xx1] @ Fri Jul 09 09:57:30 MDT 2021 (1625846250347)
2021-07-09 09:57:30,347 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2021-07-09 09:57:30,348 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': 172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:30,348 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:30,550 ERROR o.a.j.e.ConvertListeners: RemoteException occurred while replacing Remotable item.
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 5890; nested exception is: 
    java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /172.xx.xxx.xx8 using port 5890
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:337) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:470) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:381) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl.<init>(RemoteSampleListenerImpl.java:43) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ConvertListeners.addNode(ConvertListeners.java:77) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:975) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /172.xx.xxx.xx8 using port 5890
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324) ~[?:?]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257) ~[?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:181) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324) ~[?:?]
    ... 28 more
2021-07-09 09:57:30,556 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': 172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:30,556 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.xx.xxx.xx8
2021-07-09 09:57:30,751 ERROR o.a.j.e.ConvertListeners: Error replacing class org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement by wrapper: class org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 5889; nested exception is: 
    java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /172.xx.xxx.xx8 using port 5889
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:337) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:470) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:381) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerImpl.<init>(RemoteThreadsListenerImpl.java:58) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ConvertListeners.addNode(ConvertListeners.java:63) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:975) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /172.xx.xxx.xx8 using port 5889
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324) ~[?:?]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257) ~[?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:181) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324) ~[?:?]
    ... 28 more
2021-07-09 09:57:30,770 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.rconfigure(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:152) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1839) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1411) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:442) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.writeObject(HashTree.java:951) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1840) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1411) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:442) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.writeObject(HashTree.java:951) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:155) ~[?:?]
    ... 21 more
2021-07-09 09:57:30,773 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper
2021-07-09 09:57:30,773 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
2021-07-09 09:57:33,605 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started:[]
2021-07-09 09:57:33,606 ERROR o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: The following remote engines have not started:[172.xx.xxx.xx1]
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong or need to change, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have same JMeter installation/version in all machines?

Comment: Yes they all have the same, Jmeter 5.4.1 on all machines, same Java version openjdk 11, and Linux OS currently Ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: @Jordan did you ever find a solution? I'm up against the same thing. With SSL disabled, the rmi connections work fine. But once I enable SSL (including the addition of the keystore), I get these same bind exceptions. But netstat doesn't show the ports as being in use.

Comment: @Blake No, I was never able to find a solution for the issue unfortunately... I also found at certain levels I was trying to achieve the SSL started to throw errors. So I ended up running tests without distributed mode. With each machine running its own tests and reporting the results to a db to query for compiled results. Let me know if you do end up figuring it out though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the `client.rmi.localport` setting make sure that **it is the same on master and all the slaves**

So my expectation is that if you add the next line:

```
client.rmi.localport=5888
```

to all the slaves *user.properties* file you setup should start working normally.

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: Issue still occurs with that line added to slaves, it looks like getting the same errors.